# How to correctly query in flatMap operator?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I get a list of chats in `json` format from the server. I push them into class `ChatsModel`. And there is field `userId` in this class, that is in each chat there is an `userId` of that user. There isn't other information about the user. And there is one field for information about user of the Type `UserMessagesResponse`

So, at the begining that `userMessagesResponse` equals null

After I got the chat List and `userId`, I have to send another request for get information about the user. I do it this way:

```
private void loadChatsFromNetwork(int count, AccessDataModel accessDataModel) {
String accessToken = accessDataModel.getAccessToken();

Flowable<ChatsModel> chatsModelSingle = getChatsApi().getChats(count, accessToken, Constants.api_version)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(chatsModel -> {
            RealmList<Item> items = chatsModel.getResponse().getItems();
            StringBuilder userIds = new StringBuilder();

            for (Item item : items) {
                userIds.append(item.getMessage().getUserId()).append(",");
            }

            return loadUsersById(userIds, chatsModel);
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

chatsModelSingle.subscribe(chatsModel -> {
            Log.d(TAG, chatsModel.getResponse().getItems().first().getMessage().getMessagesUserItem().getFirstName());
            chatsRepository.updateChatsData(chatsModel);
            iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsSuccess(chatsModel);
        },
        throwable -> {
            iGetChatsCallback.onGetChatsError(throwable.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "onError() " + throwable.getMessage());
        });
}

private ChatsModel loadUsersById(StringBuilder userIds, ChatsModel chatsModel) {

MyApplication.getChatsApi().getUsersByChats(userIds.toString(), "photo_100")
        .subscribe(messagesUser -> {

            RealmList<Item> item = chatsModel.getResponse().getItems();

            for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
                Message message = item.get(i).getMessage();

                RealmList<UserMessagesResponse> messagesUserItemList = messagesUser.getUserMessagesResponse();
                for (UserMessagesResponse messagesResponse : messagesUserItemList) {
                    if (messagesResponse.getUid().equals(message.getUserId())) {
                        message.setMessagesUserItem(messagesResponse);
                        chatsModel.getResponse().getItems().get(i).setMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            }

        });

return chatsModel;
}
```

All these actions occur in the block of the `flatMap` operator, because I need to push received information about the user into the `userMessagesResponse` field of the `ChatsModel` class. And in case of success, I send the `chatsModel` to the adapter

Both requests are working correclty. I'm getting `userId` list and information about the user.

The problem is that after the chatsModel returns in flatMap, where `return chatsModel`, nothing happens further, the `subscriber` doesn't react in any way.

**Question**: How to fix this and generally how to properly solve such problems?

Answer (score 1):

The `flatMap()` operator is passed a function which returns an `Observable()`. In your code, you are return a `ChatsModel`. It may be sufficient to return `Observable.just(loadUsersById(userIds, chatsModel))`, as that would be what `flatMap()` is expecting.

To solve a problem of this kind in the more general situation, start with a very simple model of the problem:

```
Observable<Integer> chatHistory;
...
Observable<Long> getInfoAboutI(Integer i) {
  return Observable.just( 1L );
}
...
chatHistory
  .flatMap( i -> getInfoAboutI(i) )
  .subscribe( j -> logger.debug("j: " + j));
```

This way you don't get mired down in the details and can tune your understanding of the reactive model.